# Cognito getIdentityId() does not work in swift for unauthenticated user

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-cognito

I have the following code for getting the Cognito ID via unauthenticated user in swift for an IOS app:-

```
import Foundation

import AWSCore
import AWSCognito

class CognitoInit {

   func getCognitoIdentityId() -> String {

    let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:.USEast1,
                                                            identityPoolId:"My_idenitity_pool_id_in_aws")

    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:.USEast1, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)

    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

    credentialsProvider.getIdentityId().continueWithBlock { (task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
        if (task.error != nil) {
           return task.error?.localizedDescription
        }
        else {
            // the task result will contain the identity id
        return task.result
        }
        return nil
    }


    return "DEFAULT_COGNITO_ID"
   }
}
```

when getCognitoIdentityId() in a stub ViewController is called it always returns "DEFAULT_COGNITO_ID"(I am running it in an emulator). Stepping into the code via a debugger reveals that the async task does not run inside (the entire code block from if (task.error != nil) { to return nil is bypassed.

Am I missing something. Things that I can think of

1. Are there permissions needed for network/async calls that must be separately enabled?
2. Are there configurations needed in Cognito Identity Pool that I must do.
3. Are async tasks blocked in emulators?

Please help. I am new to swift development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it might just be the asynchronous nature of that call in play. Can you try the example exactly as described in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html), wait a few seconds, then try to get the identity id via

```
credentialsProvider.identityId
```

and see what happens? Since it is asynchronous, having it setup in this way won't work the way you're hoping, I think. You'll need to initiate the async call beforehand.

Comment: Thanks, I was doing something similar in Android and it was returning immediately. Any recommendations on the wait time for getting the identity ID?

Comment: Android isn't asynchronous, it was probably just cached. The time will vary enough from device to device that it's a bit of a guess, but you can time it well enough.

Comment: No I am taking an explicit effort to put it in an aysnc task.

Comment: Ah, then yes, it'd be asynchronous. That's an unfortunate disjoint between the two as is.